# When installing a package in pip, how to configure to generate an exe file?

Tags: python, pip, exe

When installing a package in pip, how to configure to generate an exe file, like this

```
Extracting twine-3.2.0rc1-py3.7.egg to c:\python37\lib\site-packages
twine 3.2.0rc1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing twine-script.py script to C:\Python37\Scripts
Installing twine.exe script to C:\Python37\Scripts
```

Comment: What do you mean by configuring `pip` to generate an exe?

Comment: Look up _console scripts entry points_.

Answer (score 2):

The keywords you are looking for are: *console script entry points*

These are a couple of references to help you package your Python project so that it creates executables (`*.exe` on Windows):

- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#console-scripts
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation